# how to Convert JavaScript array (without object name) into json (with object name)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am reading a local csv file with ajax query , and then loading read values into an array.

**This is how the string value looks like  in the csv file :**

```
"Tiger","Architect","800","DRP","5421","VFX"
```

**after loading this string into the array , the array looks like this :**

`0: (6) ["Tiger", "Architect", "800", "DRP", "5421", "VFX"]`

**now I am trying to convert this above mentioned sting into a json object to look like this :**

```
{
    "data": [
    {
    "0": "Tiger",
    "1": "Architect",
    "2": "800",
    "3": "DRP",
    "4": "5421",
    "5": "VFX"
    }]
}
```

by having all the values inside one object `data`

I tried this :

```
  var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, data1)); 
  var stringToJsonObject =  JSON.parse (arrayToString) ;
```

it converts the array to json, but with `length 6` where as I need the length to be 1

**any way to do this ?**

Comment: data is an array with an object at position 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have almost done everything, when you create object - just wrap array in []

```
const arr = ["Tiger", "Architect", "800", "DRP", "5421", "VFX"];
    
var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, [arr])); 
var stringToJsonObject =  JSON.parse (arrayToString) ; 

console.log(stringToJsonObject);
```

Comment: It works perfectly if there is just one row in csv , or one array of values , but It seems like when there are multiple rows or arrays it won't work ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const arr = ["Tiger", "Architect", "800", "DRP", "5421", "VFX"];

const result = {data: []};

result.data.push(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr)));

console.log(result);
```